# How do I add a Label to a display method in Dynamics AX 2009?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, axapta

I would think you should be able to define a label on a display method. However, I can't see it in the properties window. But there is a [Best Practice Warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530207.aspx):

```
Control label is a copy of its display method label
```

So who can either tell me how to add the label or what this error message is really about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type for the display method should be an Extended Data Type. On the EDT you should supply the label.

Answer (score 0):

Each form control must have a label either inherited from EDT/Enum or explicitely set on the control. The label set on the control must not be the same as the EDT/Enum's label. I suppose in your scenario it is the same, and in order to get rid of this BP warning you should just clear the label in the control properties. If you want the label to be different you can change it in the control properties or in the Extended Data Type/Base Enum properties but then it will be changed everywhere througout the system.